# ASSERT fail on creating D2D rendertarget

Tags: c++, mfc, assert, direct2d

I am building a MFC c++ program.

This program contains a class called faceTracking. This class normally had only one drawing job an thus I only passed on the MFC object it needed to draw to. This worked fine.

Recently the program changed a bit and now I need this class to not only draw the picture, but also to draw some text to the screen. So I changed some things and now I pass on the complete MFC object and use getDlgItem on creating the rendertarget to pass the correct hwnd to Direct2D:

```
D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES rtProps = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties();
rtProps.pixelFormat = D2D1::PixelFormat( DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE);
rtProps.usage = D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_USAGE_GDI_COMPATIBLE;
hr = d2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
    rtProps,
    D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(GetDlgItem(hWnd,1010), size),
    &renderTarget
    );
```

The way I see it this changes nothing. Because normally on making an FaceTracker object I would do this:

```
faceTracker = new FaceTracking(getDlgItem(hWnd,1010), d2DFactory);
```

And I changed it to this:

```
faceTracker = new FaceTracking(hWnd, d2DFactory);
```

So it should make no difference. But it does:
the program always ran fine, now on starting it the following error appears:

[image: Assertion error]
If I press ignore the program runs fine. No more errors, it is only an assertion fail.
The error happens at this statement:

```
hr = d2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
    rtProps,
    D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(GetDlgItem(hWnd,1010), size),
    &renderTarget
    );
```

And is thrown here:

```
CWnd* CWnd::GetDlgItem(int nID) const
{
    ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd));

    if (m_pCtrlCont == NULL)
        return CWnd::FromHandle(::GetDlgItem(m_hWnd, nID));
    else
        return m_pCtrlCont->GetDlgItem(nID);
}
```

So, my actual question is: why is there an assertion fail and why does there not seem to be an actual error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say 'on starting it', so probably before the window is created? As per the location where the assertion occurs (ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd));), m_hWnd (i.e., the window you're calling GetDlgItem() on) isn't created yet. This will result in GetDlgItem() returning null, which probably causes causes your d2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget() call to fail, and the code examining the HRESULT that is returned will make sure nothing bad happens afterward.

To avoid the assertion, I think (without knowing more about your program) you could avoid that by putting

```
if (IsWindow(m_hWnd)) {
    ... create render target
}
```

around the part that makes the render target.